# How to get the physical location of a reference?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, reference, path

I want to know where the references of our project physically stored on the machine but I don't know how. Viewing their properties doesn't help. Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my VS2010 ASP.NET project when I right click on a reference I can see Path as one of the propertes.  Is this what you are after?

Answer (score 2):

Try [VSCommands 2010](http://vscommands.com/download) extension. It adds 'Open File Location' to the context menu of a reference and will take you straight to the folder where your reference is on a drive.

Answer (score 0):

For files opened in your IDE, simply hold the mouse pointer over the editor tab. The tooltip which is appearing, shows the full path information.
Is this what you are looking for?